# uwp inherited property data binding not updating the UI

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding

**3 steps nested string property is not updating the UI. When I update the EvidenceName property it doesnt reflect on the UI right away until I navigate back and come again on this page in which case the viewmodel is initialized again.**

I have a xaml page with following code :

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedEvidence.EvidenceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

ViewModel property in code behind :

```
public EvidenceViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new EvidenceViewModel();
```

Selected Evidence property within the EvidenceViewModel :

```
    public Evidence SelectedEvidence
    {
        get => _selectedEvidence;
        set => Set(ref _selectedEvidence, value); //this calls for RaisePropertyChanged
    }
```

EvidenceViewModel derives from Observable class for raising property changes.

```
public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

EvidenceName property within the Evidence class

```
    public string EvidenceName
    {
        get { return _evidenceName; }
        set 
        {
            if (_evidenceName != value)
            {
                _evidenceName = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

### Update 1

if I put a simple string property directly in EvidenceViewModel and bind the UI textblock to that string property than the changes reflect in real time as expected.

### Update 2

After some further debugging I found out that any property which is being inherited by the class from parent class doesnt work well in binding, so **EvidenceName** property was actually coming from parent class **EvidenceBase** and was being inherited into child class **Evidence**.

### Update 3

Code for Evidence class in **Nswagger generated file for client**

[image: image 1]

Code for EvidenceBase class

[image: image 2]

**EvidenceName** property which actually exists in **EvidenceBase** class

[image: image 3]

**RasiePropertyChanged** code in **EvidenceBase**

[image: image 5]

Comment: Can you provide the source code of `RaisePropertyChanged` please? It is a bit odd that the code contains `Set`, `OnPropertyChanged` and `RaisePropertyChanged`, do they all come from the same MVVM toolkit?

Comment: @MartinZikmund the raise property changed mechanism comes from the generated nswag file, as these model classes are actually db tables in dotnetcore and nswagger is being used to link that with client app.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Please see the Update 3 of my question that might help clarify ur question about PropertyChanged, and this propertyChanged event works fine for all properties unless they are being inherited from an abstract class like in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to let the `Evidence` class inherit from the `Observable` class and call the `OnPropertyChanged` method in EvidenceName.

For example:

```
public class Evidence:Observable
{
    private string _evidenceName;
    public string EvidenceName
    {
        get { return _evidenceName; }
        set
        {
            if (_evidenceName != value)
            {
                _evidenceName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EvidenceName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I have tested the code from your **Update 3**, and I found that the problem is the overrides in `Evidence` class.
Please check the following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.SelectedEvidence.EvidenceName = "testName";
}


public abstract partial class EvidenceBase : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    private string _evidenceName;
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("evidenceName",Required =Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default,NullValueHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string EvidenceName
    {
        get { return _evidenceName; }
        set
        {
            if(_evidenceName!=value)
            {
                _evidenceName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("EvidenceName");
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public partial class Evidence : EvidenceBase, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

//Remove the override of PropertyChanged property and RaisePropertyChanged method to avoid hide the ones inherited from base class.
}

public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class EvidenceViewModel:Observable
{
    private Evidence _selectedEvidence;
    public Evidence SelectedEvidence
    {
        get { return _selectedEvidence; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedEvidence, value);
        }
    }
    public EvidenceViewModel()
    {
        _selectedEvidence = new Evidence();
    }
}
```

If the code cannot state your code about PropertyChanged exactly, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Cant do that because the raise property changed mechanism comes from the generated nswag file, as these model classes are actually db tables in dotnetcore and nswagger is being used to link that with client app. Please see the Update 3 of my question that might help clarify about PropertyChanged, and this propertyChanged event works fine for all properties unless they are being inherited from an abstract class like in this case.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you could check the update to see if it can meet your requirements.

Comment: yes your updated solution seems to work I just commented out the Propertychanged event and RaisePrpertyChanged in "Evidence" class. But the issue is this file is auto generated by the nswag file so i am not sure how to configure the nswag file or model classes so everytime the nswag_Generated file is generated it doesnt include propertyChanged event in Child classes, and what if child class also has some propertyies of its own not sure how to handle that one.

Comment: But in any case your answer addresses the core issue, so I am marking it as done :)

Comment: I guess I should just make interfaces and add all child properties manually in classes, and remove parent abstract classes completely?